# how to calculate rows total onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate column Number when I select married total are shown only married and when I select Unmarried total are shown only unmarried and if none of above total are show both.

```js
function filterText() {
  var rex = new RegExp($('#filterText').val().join('|'));
  if (rex == "/all/") {
    clearFilter()
  } else {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content').filter(function() {
      return rex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
  }

}

function clearFilter() {
  $('.filterText').val('');
  $('.content').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='filterText' multiple="multiple" name="filterText[]" style='display:inline-block' onclick='filterText()'>
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value='1'>Married</option>
  <option value='2'>Unmarried</option>
  <option value='all'>All</option>
</select>



<table id="table_format" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Married
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>Married</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Married</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>800</td>
      <td>All</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

just I want to calculate particular selected value. 
if any solutions, please help me and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each` to loop thru the `.content`, check if the text is including in the array, if it is, show and add the total.

Note: I added an `id` to `td` total. This is to make it easier to update the cell.

```js
function filterText() {

  var data = $("#filterText").val();
  var isAll = data.includes("All");
  var total = 0;

  $(".content").hide().each(function() {
    if (isAll || data.includes($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text().trim())) {
      $(this).show();
      total += +$(this).find("td:eq(2)").text();
    }
  })

  $("#total").text(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='filterText' multiple="multiple" name="filterText[]" style='display:inline-block' onclick='filterText()'>
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value='Married'>Married</option>
  <option value='Unmarried'>Unmarried</option>
  <option value='Widow'>Widow</option>
  <option value='All'>All</option>
</select>



<table id="table_format" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Married
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>Married</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Married</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Widow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td id="total">800</td>
      <td>All</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or you can use jQuery `filter` to filter the `tr` that is including the selected value. You can `reduce` the shown `tr` to get the total.

```js
function filterText() {
  var data = $("#filterText").val();
  var shown = $(".content").hide().filter(function() {
    return data.includes($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text().trim()) || data.includes("All");
  }).show().get();

  var total = shown.reduce((c, v) => {
    return c + +$(v).find("td:eq(2)").text()
  }, 0);

  $("#total").text(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='filterText' multiple="multiple" name="filterText[]" style='display:inline-block' onclick='filterText()'>
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value='Married'>Married</option>
  <option value='Unmarried'>Unmarried</option>
  <option value='Widow'>Widow</option>
  <option value='All'>All</option>
</select>



<table id="table_format" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Married
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>Married</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Married</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Unmarried</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>Widow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td id="total">800</td>
      <td>All</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Suppose that, i add one more filter like that :- widow and also create table tr as a same  like married and unmarried now how to calculate the total

Comment: If you want to create widow option, just add `<option value='Widow'>Widow</option>`, it will calculate the total

Comment: after create widow option like you tolled me, total are calculate but  when i'm select married or other option this will not work and if i select all option then total are show and correct.

Comment: Ok I will post .

Comment: <select id='filterText' multiple="multiple" name="filterText[]" style='display:inline-block' onclick='filterText()'>
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value='Married'>Married</option>
  <option value='Unmarried'>Unmarried</option>
  <option value='Widow'>Widow</option>
  <option value='All'>All</option>
</select>
and i just add rows in my table

Comment: <tr class="content">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Deep</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td id="did">widow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Deep</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td id="did">widow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td id="total">800</td>
      <td id="did">All</td>
    </tr>

Comment: This is your script:-
function filterText() {
  var data = $("#filterText").val();
  var shown = $(".content").hide().filter(function() {
    return data.includes($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text().trim()) || data.includes("All");
  }).show().get();

  var total = shown.reduce((c, v) => {
    return c + +$(v).find("td:eq(3)").text()
  }, 0);

  $("#total").text(total);
}

Comment: id = did is only  display none nothing else.

Comment: I updated  my select and working fine. Please check

Comment: just tell me all those changes are in code by me is it correct or not..? in above chat i send you code.

Comment: Not the same. You changed `td:eq(3)` to `td:eq(4)` and `td:eq(2)` to `td:eq(3)`

Comment: Ok thanks so much where i mistake,and  now this will work. and one more question is:-  what is eq  "td:eq(3)" ? please explain me.

Comment: now again thank you so much it's very help full for me. Thanks a lot for right path for me.